# Multiple If statements - not returning the correct value

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I am using tkinter to design a GUI in which a user will enter specific information and after the 'Create' button is clicked, that information will be put in a specific order and the output will be displayed to the user in a text box. The issue I'm having is with the design of the 'Create' function. I believe I have to use multiple If-statements in order to accomplish this, but the output I get in the text box is "tcpdump -i eth1 None host 9.9.9.9NoneNone". Obviously, I do not want the "None's" included, how can I correct this? Below is my 'Create' function.

Thanks,

```
    def create(self):
        data = "tcpdump "
        data += "-i " + self.int_entry.get() + " "


        if self.anyInt.get():
            data += "any "
        if self.src_entry.get() and not self.srcIP.get():
            data += "host " + self.src_entry.get() + " "
        elif self.src_entry.get() and self.srcIP.get():
            data += "src " + self.src_entry.get()
        data += self.AndOr.get() + " "
        if self.notDst.get():
            data += "not "
        if self.dst_entry.get() and not self.dstIP.get():
            data += "host " + self.dst_entry.get()
        elif self.dst_entry.get() and self.dstIP.get():
            data += "dst" + " " + self.dst_entry.get()
        data += self.AndOrport.get()
        if self.notSrcPort.get():
            data += "not "
        if self.srcport_entry.get():
            data += "src port " + self.srcport_entry.get() + " "
        data += self.SrcDstport.get()
        if self.notDstPort.get():
            data += "not "
        if self.dstport_entry.get():
            data += "dst port " + self.dstport_entry.get()


        self.filterData.delete(0.0, END)
        self.filterData.insert(0.0, data)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You really need to limit the amount of code that you post. This is way too much code to expect us to dig through. You need to debug to narrow the code down, and post a smaller example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Comment: I think you missed the "post a smaller example that *reproduces* the problem" part from @Carcigenicate 's comment, you only cropped your code, but it's not reproducible anymore

Comment: All I can see is many `if` statements under one function. I don't think you can say `if if elif if if elif if if`. Please use proper indention.

Comment: You're keep getting your `None`'s because of lines like `data += self.AndOrport.get()` or `data += self.SrcDstport.get()` those which outside of your `if` logic. So append the logic to them too or just cut `None`'s from final result.

Comment: @CommonSense Thank you for the reply, however, even when I add the if logic to those lines, I still get "None" in the final output. I did come to discover the issue in which the None's show up is where the radiobuttons are used. Did I create my radiobuttons incorrectly?        self.AndOr = StringVar()
  self.AndOr.set(None)
  
  Radiobutton(frame2, text = "And", variable = self.AndOr, value =" and").pack(side="left", padx=25)
  Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Or", variable = self.AndOr, value =" or").pack(side="left", padx=15)

Comment: @Clyde, if you're doesnt figure this out yet, ok, when you do `self.AndOr.set(None)` it's a same thing as `some_string = str(None)` and I think that now it's obvious why `None`'s are still here (spoiler! *cause your logic fails*). So I recommend not only append that logic, but take a look on your `StringVar`s! Default value for `StringVar` should be an empty string `''`. Got it? Try this out!

Comment: @Clyde, and if you really want Nones as default - just check for them then! Not like `if self.AndOrport.get():`, but `if self.AndOrport.get() != 'None':`. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684739/why-do-tkinters-radio-buttons-all-start-selected-when-using-stringvar-but-not-i) might be interesting for you, if you using `None` just because of default radiobutton's look.

Answer (score 1):

You must use one time if, then else if.
You can also work with cases. Meet the library and take a good book about C++ and C developing. Or Online-Tutorials.